# Is it possible in any way to use wildcards in slf4j configuration with Spring? (NOT as a root logger!)

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

Although there are a few other similar questions, they all seem to misunderstand logging configuration with regards to wildcards / root loggers. I have a different issue.

I have a code structure as follows:

Service 1

```
com.some.package.service1
    |-> subpackage1
    |-> subpackage2
```

Service 2

```
com.some.package.service2
    |-> subpackage1
    |-> subpackage2
```

I would like to set the log levels of, say, all loggers of classes in `subpackage1` to `DEBUG`, while setting the log levels of all loggers of classes in `subpackage2` to `WARN` while leaving the rest at, say, `INFO`.

I had hoped that I would be able to simply configure something like the following:

```
logging:
    level:
        com.some.package: INFO
        com.some.package.*.subpackage1: DEBUG
        com.some.package.*.subpackage2: WARN
```

Unfortunately, this does not work at all - the configuration with a wildcard in it is silently ignored. Since I have numerous services, I don't want to clog up my configuration file with numerous package logging definitions which also have to be updated whenever I add a new service. Changing the code structure is unfortunately not an option for me.

1. Is it possible to do this using slf4j, either through plain configuration or programmatically (ideally using only the slf4j API, but I could live with an implementation-specific solution)?
2. If not, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Possible alternatives: Filter on the appender level, or external post-processing of the created file (during log rotation or intake into Logstash or such). But these two will have the drawback that code guards a la `logger.isInfoEnabled` won't work (the Logger won't know that the appender will discard the output later).

Comment: How about dynamic generation of the logging configuration file at build or deploy time (from a template and the list of services that can be discovered at that time)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 1) is unfortunately not an option for me, as I would like to use the code guards to log less/more specifics depending on the log level (e.g. `DEBUG` logs Method entry/exit-points, `TRACE` logs arguments/returns as well). 2) Might be a possibility, the only drawback is that it necessitates the use of a script that is not a configuration file or in the code base itself (although I guess something like ANT might be able to do it) - I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: How come your build script is not part of the code base? Isn't there a `pom.xml` or such?  (In all honesty, I would just update that logger configuration manually when you add a service. No need to overengineer things. You need to make a commit to add the new service and its own configuration anyway, don't you? Most importantly, this also gives you flexibility to configure logging for some services differently in case you need that -- for troubleshooting etc)

Comment: I misspoke - I do have a `build.gradle` as I am using Gradle. I just meant that it is not in the source code and would likely have to be invoked by the build script as a pre-compilation step.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using, unfortunately, using the specific Logback Classic Logger implementation.

The end result is something like:

```
@Component
public class PackageScanningLoggingConfiguration {

    // Fields
    // ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        initLoggingLevels();
    }

    private void initLoggingLevels() {
        String basePackage = getBasePackage();

        List<String> candidatePackageNames = Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages())
                .filter(pkg -> pkg.getName().startsWith(basePackage))
                .filter(pkg -> {
                    String packageName = pkg.getName();
                    return packageName.contains(subpackage1Package) 
                        || packageName.contains(subpackage2Package);
                })
                .map(Package::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        candidatePackageNames.forEach(this::setConfiguredLoggingLevel);
    }

    private void setConfiguredLoggingLevel(final String packageName) {
        // ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
        // org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
        val logger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(packageName);
        if (logger != null) {
            if (packageName.endsWith(subpackage1Package)) {
                logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(subpackage1Level));
            } else if (packageName.endsWith(subpackage2Package)) {
                logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(subpackage2Level));
            }
        }
    }

    // resolve com.some.package.* to specific instance
    private String getBasePackage() {
        // In my case, I have only two "types" of services, so this
        // returns either com.some.package.service1 or com.some.package.service2
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, due to Logback internals, it seems that for this solution to work, my root package (`com.some.package`) has to be set to `TRACE` and all others have to be lower than that - the other way around does not seem to work.

Due to this, I don't like this solution very much (it works, but it's kind of weird). I'll leave this question open for a bit in case anyone has an idea of a better way to do this.